# res.locals returned undefined

Tags: node.js, express, templating

I'm trying to set some *response-specific* variables, and I'm getting `undefined` for `res.locals` when I log it from within my middleware, but it returns the function just fine if I log it from within a route function.

```
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(function (res, req, next) {
  console.log("res.locals from app.use middleware: ", res.locals);
  // res.locals.boom = 'nice';
  // res.locals.zoom = 'yeah!';
  next();
});
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have your request & response objects backwards.  Obviously if you know the difference in your code, naming doesn't matter, but best to keep things named correctly.

```
app.use( function (request, response, next) {
    // stuff
});
```

I can't recall off the top of my head, but I believe you want:

```
request.app.locals;
```

using my example above.  Again, not 100% sure.  You can always console out the request object to check.

Comment: Double checking, and yes, request.app.locals if you want to store locals from inside middleware/modules you write so that ejs templates can access them (or any other system that uses locals)

Answer (score 2):

The `app.locals` object is a JavaScript Function, which when invoked with an object will merge properties into itself, providing a simple way to expose existing objects as local variables.

```
app.locals({
  title: 'My App',
  phone: '1-250-858-9990',
  email: 'me@myapp.com'
});

app.locals.title
// => 'My App'

app.locals.email
// => 'me@myapp.com'
```

Comment: I just read that in Node.js in Action, like literally ten seconds ago. Not what I was asking about, but really interesting feature. I'm about to try it out!

Comment: What did you exactly want to know?

Comment: Why I can't seem to set res.locals.

Comment: res.locals only persist for the life of the request. app.locals persist for the life of the application. http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals